# With jena, how do I add dataProperty to an Individual

Tags: jena, owl

I want to add an instance to my ontology file that has data attributes, but when I add dataProperty, I find that the added data cannot specify the data type.
my Code:

```
    public final static String NAME_SPACE = "http://www.semanticweb.org/tangyuan/ontologies/myOntology#";
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    OntModel model1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    model1.read("file:./myOntology.owl");
    OntClass oc = model1.getOntClass(NAME_SPACE + "患者");//获得病人类

    Individual individual = oc.createIndividual(NAME_SPACE + "jane");
    DatatypeProperty dp = model1.getDatatypeProperty(NAME_SPACE + "twoh血糖值");
    model1.add(individual, dp, "7.0");
    RDFWriter rdfWriter = model1.getWriter("RDF/XML");
    rdfWriter.write(model1, new FileOutputStream("myOntology.owl"), "RDF/XML");
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

the myontology.owl file result

```
 <myOntology:患者 rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tangyuan/ontologies/myOntology#jane">
<myOntology:twoh血糖值>7.0</myOntology:twoh血糖值>
```

the dataProperty is

```
<myOntology:twoh血糖值>7.0</myOntology:twoh血糖值>
```

but I want

```
  <myOntology:twoh血糖值 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">7.0</myOntology:twoh血糖值>
```

how can I add

```
rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
```

to the dataProperty value?
Can anyone help me. thankyou

Comment: You used a Java String in the `add` method, thus it becomes a string literal. Instead use Java double primitive value, i.e. `model1.addLiteral(individual, dp, 7.0f);` - or even more simple `individual.addLiteral(dp, 7.0f);` given that `Individual` objects are backed by the model been created from

Comment: oh,right,thank you vary much!!!!!!!!